# Calculate stdev over a variable range in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table format is as follows:

```
Date       ID   subID   value
-----------------------------
7/1/1996   100    1     .0543
7/1/1996   100    2     .0023
7/1/1996   200    1    -.0410
8/1/1996   100    1    -.0230
8/1/1996   200    1     .0121
```

I'd like to apply STDEV to the value column where date falls within a specified range, grouping on the ID column.

Desired output would like something like this:

```
DateRange, ID, std_v
1 100 .0232
2 100 .0323
1 200 .0423
```

One idea I've had that works but is clunky, involves creating an additional column (which I've called 'partition') to identify a 'group' of values over which STDEV is taken (by using the OVER function and PARTITION BY applied to 'partition' and 'ID' variables).

Creating the partition variable involves a CASE statement prior where a given record is assigned a partition based on its date falling within a given range (ie,

```
...
, partition = CASE 
                 WHEN date BETWEEN '7/1/1996' AND '10/1/1996' THEN 1
                 WHEN date BETWEEN '10/1/1996' AND '1/1/1997' THEN 2
...
```

Ideally, I'd be able to apply STDEV and the OVER function partitioning on the variable ID and variable date ranges (eg, say, trailing 3 months for a given reference date).  Once this works for the 3 month period described above, I'd like to be able to make the date range variable, creating an additional '@dateRange' variable at the start of the program to be able to run this for 2, 3, 6, etc month ranges.

Comment: IMO you are on the right track, in terms of what needs to be done. Where exactly are you getting stuck?

Comment: Why not simply use `where` with start date and end date?

Comment: @Alex, not stuck, per se, just manually creating partitions for dozens of intervals seems inefficient and I'd prefer a more elegant solution

Comment: @ZoharPeled, not sure I follow your thinking.  I'd like to calculate stdev over data points for multiple intervals within a single block; applying a where clause would obviously only allow me to calculate one at a time (ie, where date between 7/1/1996 and 10/1/1996 will only get me stdev for the first 'partition').

Comment: I see. well, In that case, adding another calculated column seems like a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up coming upon a solution to my question.

You can join the original table to a second table, consisting of a unique list of the dates in the first table, applying a BETWEEN clause to specify desired range.

Sample query below.

Initial table, with columns (#excessRets):
Date, ID, subID, value

Second table, a unique list of dates in the previous, with columns (#dates):
Date

```
select d.date, er.id, STDEV(er.value)
from #dates d
inner join #excessRet er
on er.date between DATEADD(m, -36, d.date) and d.date
group by d.date, er.id
order by er.id, d.date
```

To achieve the desired next step referenced above (making range variable), simply create a variable at the outset and replace "36" with the variable.